# Why is my input not being passed into the if statements?

Tags: c, fgets

Here is my code:

```
#include "game.h"

#define LINEINPUT 30

int loadMainMenu(void);


void playGame()
{
    Cell board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH];
    char input[LINEINPUT + EXTRA_SPACES];
    printInstructions();

    while( getchar() != '\n' );

    initialiseBoard(board);

    while(TRUE)
    {
        displayBoard(board, NULL);
        printf("At this stage of the program, only two commands are acceptable:\n");
        printf("load <g>\n");
        printf("quit\n");

        fgets(input, LINEINPUT , stdin);

        if(input[strlen(input) - 1] != '\n')
        {
            printf("BUFFER OVERFLOW\n");
            readRestOfLine();
            EXIT_FAILURE;
            continue;
        }

        if(strcmp(input, "test") == 0)
        {
            printf("success!\n");
            continue;
        }


        if(strcmp(input, "load 1") == 0)
        {
            printf("lfdsfsdfoad");
            loadBoard(board, BOARD_1);
            continue;
        }

        if(strcmp(input, "load 2") == 0)
        {
            loadBoard(board, BOARD_2);
            continue;
        }

        if(strcmp(input, "quit") == 0)
        {
            loadMainMenu();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

i have cut it down so that it doesn't take up too much space. I was editing some of it this morning trying to fix things up and somehow, it doesnt read my inputs anymore. Well it does read my inputs but doesnt use strcmp to check if input matches and run the functions in the if statements. It was working fine previously but i did not change anything much.

Comment: Can you give a sample test outputs?

Comment: You should check the return value from `fgets()` to know whether you have any data to process.  Whether that's the main problem is open to debate, but always check your input operations — they have a nasty habit of failing when you'd rather they didn't.  Also, your line `while( getchar() != '\n' );` is not safe; if it reaches EOF before getting a newline, your program will run forever without doing anything useful.  `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') ;` would be safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As evidenced by your first `if` statement, `fgets()` returns strings with the `\n` line ending present. You'll want to either strip off that character, or add it to the strings you're testing against.